# pass parameters to mysql_connect function from a different file

Tags: php, mysql

I have two php files called `dbcon.php` and `user.php`. 
This is my `user.php` file

```
<?php
/* variable needed for the user to connect to the database */
$host = "localhost"; //your database host name
$dbuser = "root"; //your database user name
$dbpassword = "123"; //your database password
$dbase = "mysitedb"; //your database
?>
```

This is my `dbcon.php` file

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect($host,$dbuser,'wecarealways');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbase, $con);

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysql_error());
  }
 else {
      echo 'successful';
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I need to connect to the database called `mysitedb` bot it does not get connected. I think problem is with the separate `user.php` file. I need to know how to give parameters to `mysql_connect()` in this case.
thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You can either put everything in the same file, or `include()` your top code in it, which is what you're **not** doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`require`](http://php.net/require) or [`include`](http://php.net/include) your `user.php` file to import the contents of that file. At the top of `dbcon.php`, you need something akin to:

```
include("user.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

dbcon.php should be

```
<?php
//include parameters
include("user.php");
//connect to database (using mysqli, mysql is deprecated) or die and print the error
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,'yourpassword',$dbase) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
//If it was possible to connect to db, print 'Successful' 
echo 'Successful';
//Close the connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
 mysql_connect ("$host","$dbusername","$dbpassword");
```

Comment: This answer is being flagged as low quality. "Try this" does not suggest confidence. If you are not sure this will solve the problem, consider posting it as a comment to the question instead. A question having an answer often prevents other users, who could help, from looking at the question.

Comment: i am sure about this. thanks for your advice. i have edited that. @Popnoodles

Answer (score 0):

You dbcon.php should look like this..

```
<?php

include("user.php");

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser, $dbpassword);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($dbase, $con);

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysqli_error());
  }
 else {
      echo 'successful';
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```